# cluster point of a set of decimals

Tags: real-analysis

I was given this question on an exam today and was wondering what the answer was. The question asked for the set of cluster points of $\left\{\frac{m}{10^n} : m \in \mathbb Z, n \in \mathbb N\right\}$. I originally thought the solution was all real numbers, but talked myself into putting just zero in the end. My reasoning was that a number $x_0$ is a cluster point if and only if a sequence in this interval converges to $x_0$. Regardless of the value of $m$, $\frac{m}{10^n}$ will converge to zero as $n$ tends to infinity, so I feel I got this correct, but my text didn't really cover cluster points so I'm afraid I've talked myself out of twenty points. Did I do this problem correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every real number is a limit of a sequence of numbers of the form $\frac{m}{10^n}$ for $m\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $n\in\mathbb{N}$: just take the partial sums of its decimal expansion.

Comment: Darn, I was originally thinking it was all reals based on the archimedean property of the reals (so we could draw a delta-ball around any real to include some of these points), but I just talked myself out of it. Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 0):

It is true that for fixed $m$, as $n\to\infty$, $m/10^n\to 0$, but $m$ need not be fixed. Consider the sequence $$\frac{3}{1},\;\frac{31}{10},\;\frac{314}{100},\;\frac{3141}{1000},\;\frac{31415}{10000},....$$ It converges to $\pi$, if we keep going. Indeed, we can write every real number as the limit of a sequence in this way.